# How to get Permissions in linkedin Organization Share Statistics

Tags: api, linkedin-api, analytics

I have Created App ,I need permissions to access Organizational entity how to I am do next step how to collect data? and I am already registered Marketing Developer Program

i am using following url in get method:(id Changed)

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?oauth2_access_token=AQUgrHGtHg....&q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:12345`

I am get following Error Message:

> { "serviceErrorCode": 100, "message": "Not enough permissions to
>   access: GET-organizationalEntity
>   /organizationalEntityShareStatistics", "status": 403 }

Answer (score 0):

You have requested Marketing Developer Platform but did they(Linkedin) accept Your request?
I have to write to them to accept my request :D

If they accept Your request try to put Your token in authoriztion section(baerer token) instead of paramas. 
And Your url should be like this:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:12345`

where 12345 is Your company id